# How to fix recurrent "This API project is not authorized to use this API." despite having active API keys?

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, google-api

I keep getting the "This API project is not authorized to use this API" error while using Google Maps API request (see below).

I have tried to use both iOS and Server keys, but I only get errors (30 errors so far; this shows that there is no typo in the keys), but no results. My request code is below.

What am I missing? Thanks.

```
NSString * locationURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%f%@%f%@%d%@%@%@%@", 
    @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=", 
    latitude, @",", longitude, @"&radius=", radius, @"&types=", locationType, 
    @"&key=", API_KEY];

NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:locationURL]];

NSData *theData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                        returningResponse:nil
                                                    error:nil];

NSDictionary *newJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theData
                                                        options:0
                                                          error:nil];

NSLog(@"Sync JSON: %@", newJSON);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Unrelated - your `locationURL` line should be: `NSString * locationURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=%@&key=%@", latitude, longitude, radius, locationType, API_KEY];`.

Comment: Related - make sure none of the values have any spaces in them such as `locationType`.

Comment: @rmaddy: thanks. Def an authorisation issue, no spaces in the url.

Comment: This error usually means that you didn't activate the particular API(I'm not sure how this question is related to iOS, it looks like a simple call to the places-webservice, so you must enable **Google Places API Web Service** in the console)

Comment: @Dr.Molle: thanks for your suggestion. I believe I have enabled API; see screenshot 2, the last column is all "Disable" which, I presume, means that all services were enabled.

Comment: the last column is **Google Places API for IOS** and not **Google Places API Web Service** (it's a different API)